# Vite reverse proxy not working on nginx docker setup

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, vite

I am trying to deploy a vue app on a docker nginx server. I have managed to do it correctly except the part of the vite reverse proxy that does not work properly and I can't understand why.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
# build stage
FROM node as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

my `docker-compose.yml`

```
  front-end:
    build: front-end
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - back-end
    restart: always
```

my `nginx.conf`

```
events {
}

http {
    include mime.types;

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    }
}
```

and my `vite.conf.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
    proxy: {
      '/auth/login-user': {
        target: 'http://back-end:8081/backend/auth/user/login',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true
      },
      '/user/create-user': {
        target: 'http://back-end:8081/backend/auth/user/create',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When the call is made for `login-user` for example, I get the following error

```
2023/07/18 12:26:50 [error] 29#29: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/auth/login-user" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /auth/login-user HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/login"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the rules defined in `vite.config.ts` did not apply for production mode so I had to rewrite them in the `nginx.conf` file like below

```
events {
}

http {
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /auth/login-user {
          proxy_pass http://back-end:8081/backend/auth/user/login;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location /user/create-user {
          proxy_pass http://back-end:8081/backend/auth/user/create;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }


    }
}
```